# Get a UIButton's tag from the UIButtons which are in the popover presented by this UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uibutton, uipopovercontroller

The headline seems lengthy but what I'm trying to do is quite simple.

I have a couple of identical buttons lined in a row and set their tags to 0...n. Clicking on any of them (the 2nd for example) would bring up a popover view in which there are several buttons representing different options (A, B, C, D). What I want to do is to turn the 2nd Button's title to B if we click on option B.

The problem is that the popover view does not know which Button presented it, since all popoverViews are instances of the same UIViewController class. So I am thinking of distinguishing the n buttons by setting their tags to different values. However, I don't know how to get the UIButton's tag from a button inside the popover this UIButton presented.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the problem by adding a property `tagNumber`so that after instantiating the popoverViewController's class, I set the instance's `tagNumber` to the sender's tag. Then I send the `tagNumber` back together with `sender.currentTitle`. This way, the presenter of the popover could know both the title and tag number of the UIButton.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I will solve this in swift. I will declare a delegate in the popoverViewController and have a method e.g

```
protocol popOverViewControllerDelegate: class {
 func popOverViewController(controller: PopOverViewController,
    didSelectItem buttonTitle: String)
}
```

then I will add a target action to the UIButton in the popOver

```
button.addTarget(self, action: "selected:",forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
```

the select method will have sender passed to it

```
func selected(sender:UIButton){
  delegate?.popOverViewController(self, didSelectItem: sender.currentTitle)
//dismiss viewcontroller
}
```

remember to declare

```
weak var delegate: popOverViewControllerDelegate!
```

now have the viewcontroller that called the popOver, subclass to this delegate and implement it's method. Whenever a button in the popOver is selected, this method will be called and the currentTitle of the method will be passed. You can now use that to set the currentTitle of the button that called the popOver.
In case you need further help with the last part, please ask.

Comment: That's exactly how I'm doing it now. The problem is when implementing the delegate method `func popOverViewController(controller: PopOverViewController,
    didSelectItem buttonTitle: String) ` in my presenting view controller, how do I know which button to set with this `buttonTitle`? I am thinking of passing the `sender.currentTitle` along with something like `sender.superview.superview.tag`, then I would know which button is presenting this popview. However, I am how to get this tag.